# Потребуется/потребуются набор ... и ... аппарат"

Tags: согласование

*"Потребуется набор инструментов и сварочный аппарат"*

или

*"Потребуются набор инструментов и сварочный аппарат"*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки не будет в обоих случаях. Но нас учили, что если подлежащие (набор, аппарат) одного рода (в данном случае мужского), то единственное число обязательно.

***Потребуется набор инструментов и сварочный аппарат.***

В пользу единственного числа "работает" и положение сказуемого в предложении - оно стоит раньше подлежащего, в препозиции.

[**Правило**](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-030.htm) коротко (та его часть, которая относится к вопросу):

> Если подлежащие соединяются соединительными союзами или интонацией
>   перечисления, то сказуемое имеет форму, соответствующую близстоящему
>   подлежащему (форму единственного числа), например:
>
> Встретит нас забота и нужда (Н.); Слышно было сопенье паровоза,
>   свистки, рожок стрелочника (Фад.); На глинистой отмели стояла кучка
>   туземцев и человек пять европейцев (Грин); У меня была бы прекрасная
>   библиотека, разные музыкальные, инструменты, пчельник, огород,
>   фруктовый сад (М. Г.); Разве не прекрасна каждая травинка, наполненная
>   пахучим соком, и каждое летучее семечко липы? (Пауст.).
>
> Форма множественного числа обязательна, если подлежащие обозначают
>   лица, а сказуемое - действие этих лиц: Кричали Витя, Павлик, Кирилл...
>   (Фед.); множественное число возможно и при некоторых других
>   подлежащих, в таком случае сказуемое подчеркнуто относится к каждому
>   из подлежащих: Ей нравились его прямота и непринужденность (Т.).

См. также: [**Форма сказуемого при однородных подлежащих**](http://www.durov.com/study/1337176278-2144.html).